XMLHttpRequest , net::ERR_FAILED , Axios Error
I'm creating project that has frontend in  react js and I used userfront.com's api for login and reset password in login page
The problem in console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.userfront.com/v0/tenants/rbvdmyqb/some-secure-endpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED**

I verified url
const response = await axios.post("``https://api.userfront.com/v0/tenants/rbvdmyqb/auth/reset/link``", payload, options);

This question is similar to: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add

Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

extension to your browser.
Enable it in Chrome by clicking here:

Chrome:
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?utm_source=ext_app_menu
Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search
